# Search Duplicate in a dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that is the fusion of two others.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

The index of this new dataframe are proper names and this dataframe (df) contains a column 'Letter' filled with random letters from 'A' to 'Z'.

I would like to know if there are duplicate lines for the letter 'A' and the letter 'B'.

that is to say that two lines are completely identical (ex:

```
      Letter
jeans  'A'
jeans  'A'
```

without taking into account the duplicates on the other letters.

the programme will return the number of duplicate en 'A' and 'B'.

Comment: Can you please share a sample dataframe input with expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account you want to only count the repeated values of A and B:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Letter':['A','A','A','B','B']})

repetedA = np.where(df[df.Letter.duplicated()].isin(['A']), 1, 0).sum()
repetedB = np.where(df[df.Letter.duplicated()].isin(['B']), 1, 0).sum()

print('A repeated values:', repetedA, 
      '\nB repeated values:', repetedB)
```

Output:

```
A repeated values: 2 
B repeated values: 1
```